# MageReport Security Patch Check

Tags: magento-1.9

How Mage Report Checks the security patch is updated or not? On what basis it shows the result for Magento 1.9.3.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The magereport team closely follows Magento releases and security trends in the community. Since it is not possible to see from the outside of a Magento shop which files exist on the server, so MageReport uses **`behavior-based identification patterns`**. This is possible because each Magento patch introduces subtle changes in behavior.

Apart from that, it is possible to **`request a few static files`** and derive the Magento version from that. The work of MageReport is shared on Github.

For more details, please visit: https://www.magereport.com/page/faq#how_does_it_work